# Erro com System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fui tentar instalar o pacote install-package microsoft.aspnet.mvc.pt-br para o javascript em português e a minha aplicação passou a não mais rodar, dando erro onde tudo aponta que é com o Razor, já tentei de tudo, até remover a referência e adicioná-la novamente, mas o problema persiste. Segue o erro:

```
[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c18d8738\e9228a3c\assembly\dl3\a1b5a49f\18a5dcd1_85f4d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c18d8738\e9228a3c\assembly\dl3\a1b5a49f\18a5dcd1_85f4d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c18d8738\e9228a3c\assembly\dl3\a1b5a49f\18a5dcd1_85f4d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.GetRazorSection(String virtualPath) +151
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +210
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +38
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig() +51
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +57
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +56
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +77
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +30
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9973313
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +155
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651796
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Você começou esse projeto em MVC4? A versão do Razor apontada está como a 2. Preciso que você na sua pergunta o conteúdo do `Web.Config` que está dentro do diretório *Views*.

Comment: comecei com essa <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: Está bem desatualizado seu projeto. Vou tentar uma resposta.

Comment: Olá! caro amigo, estou deixando aqui o meu comentário, pois passei por um problema semelhante a este do post. pois migrei o projeto do VS2015 para VS2017, fiz a alteração na "unha" conforme essa indicação do post (System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,) colocando para 3.0.0.0 e funcionou perfeitamente. Abraço galera!

Comment: Olá Alessandro! Fiz o mesmo também, infelizmente o Visual Studio tem alguns problemas que é resolvido apenas na gambiarra. Mas de qualquer forma obrigada pelo seu comentário.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando pacotes de versões misturadas do MVC. Aparentemente seu projeto foi iniciado na versão 4, e agora você quer usar pacotes da versão 5.

Faça um *update* completo do seu projeto, abrindo o Package Manager Console e digitando o seguinte:

```
Update-Package
```

Faça antes um backup do seu projeto.

Outra coisa que pode ser motivo de conflito é a versão do .NET Framework que, para o MVC5, precisa ser a 4.5.

Clicando com o botão direito no projeto, selecione **Properties**. Dentro da aba **Application** veja o campo **Target Framework**. Se estiver na versão 4, mude para 4.5.

Comment: Cigado, agora está dando o seguinte erro: Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Faça um *Clean*, depois um *Rebuild* da solução. Verifique também nas referências se nenhum dos pacotes está marcado com um ícone amarelo.

Comment: Sim, fiz isso. Inclusive após a atualização dos pacotes eu fechei o Visual Studio e abri novamente e fiz um Clean. Mas o problema da última mensagem persiste. As referências estão todas corretas, sem nenhum ícone de alerta. Reparei também nos pacotes que foi atualizado para o Razor <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />, não poderia ser isso a causa dessa mensagem de não estar localizando um arquivo do sistema?

Comment: Não, agora deve ser a versão do Framework. Atualizei a resposta pra você.

Comment: Já está na 4.5, tem a opção para 4.5.1, fiz uma cópia e mudei para esta versão e continua com o erro: Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Verificou as References? O `System.Web.Razor` aparece lá?

Comment: Sim, está vinculado tanto o system.web.razor quanto o system.web.webpages.razor, mas uma coisa que eu reparei é que mesmo removendo e adicionando novamente o system.web.webpages.razo, ele não fica na lista, só aparece o system.web.razor.

Comment: Vai precisar reinstalar o Razor: `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages -reinstall`.

Comment: Cigado, ele voltou ao erro inicial, eu reparei que na minha web.config da View continua informando que a versão do razor é 2.0.0.0 mesmo depois de tudo isso que fizemos. O erro é o mesmo do início: Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location

Comment: Cigado, eu consegui resolver o problema. Eu comentei em todos os lugares onde informava a versão 2.0.0.0 e informei manualmente a versão que você pediu para atualizar e funcionou. Teria outra forma dele atualizar o Razor e modificar isso automaticamente sem eu ter que fazer isso manualmente?

Comment: Automaticamente não. O que existe [é este guia que a Microsoft montou](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2). Verifique neste tutorial se não ficou faltando nada.

Comment: Obrigada Cigano!

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode simplesmente alterar a versão na "unha" o arquivo Web.config dentro da pasta View;

```
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, 
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

SUBSTITUA POR:

```
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,
 System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Faça o teste.

Comment: Olá Diego, sobre esse problema antigo, eu já tentei isso também. Porém todos os meus Helpers ficam como não existentes no Visual Studio.